# C# bouncing ball angle changing

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I am making a Windows Form program in C# where an image bounces around in the window at 45 degree angles. The part where I need help in is that I must make the program so then the user can adjust the angle that the image bounces, between 0 and 90 degrees. I cannot think of a simple way to do this and I really need help.

This is the timer code that I have so far. `intSideposition` is the left value of the image. `intTopPosition` is the top value of the image. `intLeftSpeed` is the horizontal speed of the image. `intTopSpeed` is the vertical speed of the image. 817 and 380 are the borders of the window that the image will bounce off of. Currently the image will bounce at a 45 degree angle.

```
//Moves the label by a factor of whatever intLeftSpeed is
intSidePosition = intSidePosition + intLeftSpeed;
intTopPosition = intTopPosition + intTopSpeed;
this.lblSprite.Left = intSidePosition;
this.lblSprite.Top = intTopPosition;

//Checks if the sprite has hit the boundaries of the window, causing it to bounce
if (this.lblSprite.Left <= 0)
{
    intLeftSpeed = intLeftSpeed * -1;
}
else if (this.lblSprite.Left >= 817)
{
    intLeftSpeed = intLeftSpeed * -1;
}
else if (this.lblSprite.Top >= 380)
{
    intTopSpeed = intTopSpeed * -1;
}
else if (this.lblSprite.Top <= 0)
{
    intTopSpeed = intTopSpeed * -1;
}
lblAngle.Text = intAngle.ToString();
```

Comment: showing us some code always helps

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: don't close it, that was one of my favorites when I learned computer graphics back then...

Comment: From what I can see, the only way your current code would make the image bounce at 45 angles is if intLeftSpeed == intTopSpeed ( or intLeftSpeed == -1*intTopSpeed).

For example, try running your program with intTopSpeed initialized to 0, and see what happens.

Comment: How does the image start moving ? What's the relationship between lblAngle and lblSprite ? The sprite is what you need to bounce, and lblAngle is supposed to show the desired angle ? Lastly, are you sure it's a 45 degree bounce and not 90 ? If image is moving up and to the left , it will hit left and then move to the right, but still up - that's a 90 degree bounce ? Or have I read code wrong ?

Comment: Left and top speed are already set to 1. Right now lblAngle does not do anything, because I cant figure out how to change the angles yet. Also I am absolutely sure that it is a 45 degree angle bounce.

Comment: @user1033065 - "Left and top speed are already set to 1".  That's why it is bouncing at 45 degrees.  Do what Daniel Mošmondor suggests, and vary the initial left and top speed according to the angle you want.

Comment: Yeah I had the idea of changing the speeds to change the angle, but I didnt know how to go about it. Now I remember 10th grade math and it is clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use trigonometry here, in order to have any angle for the ball.

Also, all variables should become `double`s.  Both speed and position variables!

You will initialize with something such as

```
double speedX = Math.Cos(angle);
double speedY = Mach.Sin(angle);
```

I won't tell you that angle here will be in radians, not degrees.  Ooops, I just did :)

Comment: Okay Daniel I need some more assistance. Where in my program would I put this? I tried putting it in the if statements, put the result is that the image will not even bounce. I the angle is in radians too :(

Comment: You should put this into the initialization, in the place where your previous variables were set to 1.  As for radians to degrees, figure it out yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your intLeftSpeed and intTopSpeed make the angle desired (or atleast approximate it). They are currently always equal so they always generate a 45 degree angle.